# JMS send and recv synchronization

Tags: java, jpa, jms

I have a question about best pattern for JMS message send and recv synchronization...

I have an C++ client talking to J2EE server using JAX-RS (REST) over HTTP. On the server side I have two EJBs - one for resource manipulation and other for session state tracking (@Singleton). And I need to notify client when something is changed, created or deleted on server. So I made this approach:

1 - When client connects and logs in, session bean creates temporary jms queue (non transactional) with code like:

```
connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
connection.start();
producer = session.createProducer(queue);
consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);
```

2 - Client call "listener" REST resource which calls:

```
public void listen() {
    ...
    consumer.recv(timeout);
    ...
}
```

and blocks until it got an message or timeout expires.

3 - When I make some changes in resource bean it calls

```
public void update(...) {
    em.update(...);
    producer.send(session.createMessage(CHANGE_NOTIFY_MESSAGE));
}
```

4 - "listener" resource get the message from JMS and returns it to client with changed (created) object information and than client calls "get" method to get created or changed object.

My problem is that "listener" gets message before changes are written to database (I'm using JPA), so when client asks for created or changed object, this one doesn't exist yet or has old information.

How I can modify my alghoritm to be notified only after changes are saved to database?

Thank you for ideas in advance)))

Comment: I think you need to make the session transactional and use an XA datasource for your JPA db connection. The update method runs in a transaction by default so the database change and message send will then be committed together. You need XA because you're combining two different resources (database and queue) in a single tx.

Answer (score 0):

As [Steve C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1897870/steve-c) says, I think you need to make the session transactional. An example:

```
// do the operation
em.getTransaction().begin();
em.update(p); 
em.getTransaction().commit();

// now you can send 
producer.send(session.createMessage(CHANGE_NOTIFY_MESSAGE));
```